# Xamarin Forms Popup Page Button Command Called when Page Appears

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Rg.Plugins.Popup, and I have a popup page with a button that I want to use to dismiss the popup. The popup displays just fine, and I can dismiss it at the moment with background select. But for good UX wanted a button too. The button is wired up like this:

In my XAML:

```
<Button BackgroundColor="#2B653E"
                Margin="0,20,0,0"
                Padding="10,10,10,10"
                Command="{Binding OnBtnOkTapped}"
                Text="OK"
                TextColor="White"
                x:Name="btnOk"/>
```

And in my ViewModel:

```
public ICommand OnBtnOkTapped = new Command(async () => { await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync(); });
```

I've confirmed the binding is working (other properties are working fine). But nothing was happening when I tap the button. So I put a breakpoint on this line, and found it was getting called *when the popup appears.*

It then doesn't get called (i.e. I don't hit the breakpoint) when I tap this button in the popup.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

**EDIT**: Did some further testing, changing from a Command to a Clicked and handling in the code behind rather than the ViewModel produces the expected result. Just don't understand why the ICommand is called when the page loads and not when the button is clicked.

**EDIT 2:**

As requested by @G.hakim, here is the full XAML for this page:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
             xmlns:lottie="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"
             x:Class="MyApp.PopUpPages.ReservationResult"
             BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation
            PositionIn="Center"
            PositionOut="Center"
            ScaleIn="1.2"
            ScaleOut="0.8"
            DurationIn="400"
            DurationOut="300"
            EasingIn="SinIn"
            EasingOut="SinOut"
            HasBackgroundAnimation="false"/>
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <StackLayout
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        WidthRequest="300"
        HeightRequest="400"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        Padding="30">
        <lottie:AnimationView x:Name="ResultAnimation"
             Animation="{Binding AnimationRef}"
             AutoPlay="true"
             Loop="false"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"
             HeightRequest="200"
             WidthRequest="200"
             Scale="1"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ResponseTitle}"
           Margin="0,20,0,0"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Start"
           TextColor="#2B653E"
           FontAttributes="Bold"
           FontSize="Large"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding ResponseMessage}"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="End"
           TextColor="#2B653E"/>

        <Button BackgroundColor="#2B653E"
                Margin="0,20,0,0"
                Padding="10,10,10,10"
                Clicked="Handle_Clicked"
                Text="OK"
                TextColor="White"
                x:Name="btnOk"/>       
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using MyApp.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ReservationResultViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public string ResponseTitle { get; set; }
        public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
        public string AnimationRef { get; set; }

        public ICommand OnBtnOkTapped = new Command(async () => { await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync(); });

        public ReservationResultViewModel(ReservationStatus status)
        {
            switch (status.status)
            {
                case ReservationStatus.Status.Booked:
                    //
                    ResponseTitle = "Booked!";
                    ResponseMessage = "We've received your reservation, see you then!";
                    AnimationRef = "1166-tick.json";
                    break;
                case ReservationStatus.Status.Full:
                    //
                    ResponseTitle = "Well this is embarrassing...";
                    ResponseMessage = "Looks like this is a really popular time and we're full. Head over to the Contact page though, we still might be able to help!";
                    AnimationRef = "4284-notification.json";
                    break;
                case ReservationStatus.Status.HttpError:
                    //
                    ResponseTitle = "Hmmm...";
                    ResponseMessage = "Something went wrong, but we're pretty sure its our fault. Can you check your form and try again?";
                    AnimationRef = "3932-error-cross.json";
                    break;
                case ReservationStatus.Status.ServerUnavailable:
                    //
                    ResponseTitle = "It's not you, it's me...";
                    ResponseMessage = "So sorry, it looks like the reservation service is down! Please head over to the Contact page, or try again later.";
                    AnimationRef = "4386-connection-error.json";
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Code behind for the view:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using MyAPp.Models;
using MyApp.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.PopUpPages
{
    public partial class ReservationResult : PopupPage
    {
        public ReservationResultViewModel viewModel { get; set; }

        public ReservationResult(ReservationResultViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel = vm;
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }

        async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still looking for the `ViewModel` solution for this or are you satisfied with what you have?

Comment: I’d rather the view model solution, although I can certainly ship it with what I’ve got for now. But I guess I’d still like to get my head around why this is happening.

Comment: Okay good so I need to know two things, 1st was your command working on click event before, 2nd if it was not working before do you have a separate ViewModel for your pop up or not

Comment: Yeah I’ve got a seperate ViewModel for the pop up, this is the ViewModel I’m referring to in my question, not the ViewModel for the page calling it. Can’t say about whether it was working before, I built this right into the pop up, I didn’t move something I already had in there. And I didn’t test it with Clicked until after it didn’t work with the command in the ViewModel.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add the `ViewModel` and The `View`(xaml and cs) in your question?

Comment: Done - updated the question with the code

Comment: Added an answer take a look

Answer (score 0):

All UI specific actions needs to be performed on the device main thread (UI thread).

So you command should look like this:

```
public ICommand OnBtnOkTapped = new Command( Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync()} );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. Firstly, when I call this from a Clicked event handler instead of a Command, it works just fine without needing to run against the main thread. And second, this doesn't explain why this method gets called when the page loads and doesn't get called when I tap the button (whether it works or not is not even the issue here as its not getting called).

Comment: Sorry got your situation wrong. I though the button command is executed but nothing happens.  Looking again at your code I notice that you ICommand OnBtnTapped is only a field an not a property. Try changing it to public public ICommand OnBtnOkTapped { get; internal set; } = new Command( ...)

Comment: If you want to update your question to reflect this, and if you can also answer the question as to why the command was getting fired when the page loads, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you will have to make the following changes:

Add a command to the button(XAML) something like this:

```
 Command="{Binding MoreButtonCommand}"
```

Add the same property to your ViewModel class something like this :

```
public ICommand MoreButtonCommand { get; set; }
```

In your ViewModel's Constructor initialize this property:

```
MoreButtonCommand = new Command(MoreButtonPressed);
```

Then make a void-returning method to pass as the command's parameter:

```
 private async void MoreButtonPressed(object obj)
    {
       await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
    }
```

This should work for you if it doesn't feel free to revert

Good luck

### Edit:

The reason, because this was not working, was that you were using a field, Now a `FIELD` is not what you wire up with a `BindingProperty`.A binding property only accepts properties i.e. something `public ICommand MoreButtonCommand { get; set; }` as its input hence you were not able to wire it before but now it works

Comment: Thanks for this. I should have clarified - the code for the button is wired to a Clicked event handler now because I changed it so it would at least function. You can see from my original code in the question that I had it wired up as a Command before, which wasn't working, and from the edit that I changed it to a Clicked event handler. So, excepting that, your answer is eventually saying to change the ICommand from a field to a property. I will try this, but FYI this is also provided by @Jannik R. in a comment on their answer above.

Comment: The main reason it was not working was because it was a field as soon as you change it to a property and wire it up as i have shown above it will work, make sure you remove the event handler from XAML before you use command or else you would not know if it works

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried this and it works. Can you add an explanation of why the when the Command was a field it gets called when the page loaded to your answer? I will accept it then.

Comment: Okay i will give me a minute

Comment: @MattG I have added the reason take a look

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm still not sure why I hit my breakpoint on this field though when the page loads.

Comment: Before I changed the ICommand from a field to a property, I put a breakpoint on it to see if it was being called when I tapped the button (it wasn't). However, I would hit that breakpoint as soon as the popup was called.

Comment: Well, Command accepts a property that is why it was not working, now that it is a property in place of a field it should work.

Comment: Ok, I get the why it wasn't working bit. But why would that command get called when the page loaded?

Comment: Are you talking about the part in the constructor or the actual method like in the above example `MoreButtonPressed`  method

Comment: Well, neither. If you look at my original code (in my question) for my view model, you can see that I start by declaring a couple of string properties, followed by the ICommand (field). It's this ICommand that gets called when it loads. At least, putting a breakpoint on this line, hits that breakpoint when I open the popup.

Comment: Yes that happens because when you constructor calls the ICommand and sets a value into it

Comment: It's not called in the constructor though...?

Comment: You seem confused about what exactly is your issue can you brief it so, I can tell you the answer quickly.

Comment: Well its right there in my question. I explained that there were two things happening that I didn't understand, and asked if anyone can explain these. One of these was, why was the command not getting fired when I tap the button. You have explained this. the second, was why was it getting fired when the page loads? You have not explained this.

Comment: Well it is fired because you are updating the data in it hence it is called to update the command that has been assigned to it